# Error on jhbuild bootstrap for gtk+ on OSX El Capitan

Tags: macos, gtk, osx-elcapitan, jhbuild

I tried to install GTK+ on my iMac with OSX 10.11
`$ sh gtk-osx-build-setup.sh`
went without any error, but said "yelp-tools not available".
When I did
`$ jhbuild bootstrap`
I got the following error/output:

```
W: bash has a dependency on unknown "readline" module
*** Checking out xz *** [1/22]
curl --continue-at - -L http://tukaani.org/xz/xz-5.2.1.tar.bz2 -o /Users/Noemi/gtk/source/pkgs/xz-5.2.1.tar.bz2
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1158k  100 1158k    0     0  2424k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 2423k
bunzip2 -dc "/Users/Noemi/gtk/source/pkgs/xz-5.2.1.tar.bz2" | tar xf -
*** Configuring xz *** [1/22]
./configure --prefix /Users/Noemi/gtk/inst --libdir '/Users/Noemi/gtk/inst/lib'   
./configure: line 154: /Users/Noemi/gtk/inst/bin/bash: No such file or directory
./configure: line 154: exec: /Users/Noemi/gtk/inst/bin/bash: cannot    execute: No such file or directory
*** Error during phase configure of xz: ########## Error running ./configure --prefix /Users/Noemi/gtk/inst --libdir '/Users/Noemi/gtk/inst/lib'    *** [1/22]

  [1] Rerun phase configure
  [2] Ignore error and continue to build
  [3] Give up on module
  [4] Start shell
  [5] Reload configuration
  [6] Go to phase "wipe directory and start over"
  [7] Go to phase "clean"
  [8] Go to phase "distclean"
choice:
```

Answer (score 2):

From .jhbuildrc:

```
# El Capitan needs bash to work around SIP. If you're using a
# common bootstrap directory (e.g. $HOME/.local) then override
# CONFIG_SHELL in .jhbuildrc-custom after calling setup_sdk().
```

so I added:

```
os.environ['CONFIG_SHELL'] = '/bin/bash'
```

into my .jhbuildrc-custom, just after the setup_sdk line and it appears to be working